# Why does display:block affect vertical alignment in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, vertical-alignment

See the code below. This looks alright in Chrome and Edge, but it aligns the text to the bottom in Firefox. Also [check this CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzVNQe) in different browsers to see what I mean. What is causing this?

```css
.table {display:table;}
.row {display:table-row;}
.cell{display:table-cell;}
.input input{display:block; margin:10px 0;}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell txt">
      This is text
    </div>
    <div class="cell input">
      <input type="txt">
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell txt">
      This is text
    </div>
    <div class="cell input">
      <input type="txt">
    </div>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you can add `vertical-align: middle;` to your `.cell` class. Also, I'd create the vertical spacing around items using `padding` inside the `.cell` itself. That way, all cells share the same spacing.

```css
.table {display: table;}
.row {display: table-row;}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.input input {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell txt">
      This is text
    </div>
    <div class="cell input">
      <input type="txt">
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell txt">
      This is text
    </div>
    <div class="cell input">
      <input type="txt">
    </div>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. That works for the given code. However, in my actual code I only have a margin-bottom. See the livecode here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mveZKp
align:top looks better but this is not actually aligning it in the middle. This is very visible when you add padding to the input.

Comment: It might work better to apply your spacing to the `.cell`, instead of the `input`. See my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks, putting a padding to the cell instead of to the input field seems to work!